# Java 8 Nested (Multi level) group by

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have few classes like below

```
class Pojo {
    List<Item> items;
}

class Item {
    T key1;
    List<SubItem> subItems;
}

class SubItem {
    V key2;
    Object otherAttribute1;
}
```

I want to aggregate the items based on `key1` and for each aggregation, subitems should be aggregated by `key2` in following way:

```
Map<T, Map<V, List<Subitem>>
```

How is this possible with Java 8 `Collectors.groupingBy` nesting?

I was trying something and stuck halfway at

```
pojo.getItems()
    .stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getKey1, /* How to group by here SubItem::getKey2*/)
    );
```

Note: This not same as cascaded `groupingBy` which does multilevel aggregation based on fields in the same object as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28344135/5220522)

Comment: Can you try?`pojo.getItems().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getKey1)).entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, (e)-> e.getValue().stream().map(it -> it.getSubItems().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SubItem::getKey2)))));` Im not sure about it.

Comment: @David Pérez Cabrera: I think that’ll work, but fully collecting everything into a temporary `Map<T, List<Item>>` can be quite expensive.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can’t group a single item by multiple keys, unless you accept the item to potentially appear in multiple groups. In that case, you want to perform a kind of `flatMap` operation.

One way to achieve this, is to use `Stream.flatMap` with a temporary pair holding the combinations of `Item` and `SubItem` before collecting. Due to the absence of a standard pair type, a typical solution is to use `Map.Entry` for that:

```
Map<T, Map<V, List<SubItem>>> result = pojo.getItems().stream()
    .flatMap(item -> item.subItems.stream()
        .map(sub -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(item.getKey1(), sub)))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry::getKey,
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                    Collectors.groupingBy(SubItem::getKey2))));
```

An alternative not requiring these temporary objects would be performing the `flatMap` operation right in the collector, but unfortunately, [`flatMapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) won't be there until Java 9.

With that, the solution would look like

```
Map<T, Map<V, List<SubItem>>> result = pojo.getItems().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getKey1,
                Collectors.flatMapping(item -> item.getSubItems().stream(),
                    Collectors.groupingBy(SubItem::getKey2))));
```

and if we don’t want to wait for Java 9 for that, we may add a similar collector to our code base, as it’s not so hard to implement:

```
static <T,U,A,R> Collector<T,?,R> flatMapping(
    Function<? super T,? extends Stream<? extends U>> mapper,
    Collector<? super U,A,R> downstream) {

    BiConsumer<A, ? super U> acc = downstream.accumulator();
    return Collector.of(downstream.supplier(),
        (a, t) -> { try(Stream<? extends U> s=mapper.apply(t)) {
            if(s!=null) s.forEachOrdered(u -> acc.accept(a, u));
        }},
        downstream.combiner(), downstream.finisher(),
        downstream.characteristics().toArray(new Collector.Characteristics[0]));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Holger, can you elaborate more on "accept the item to potentially appear in multiple groups". I didn't get this part.

Comment: If you group to a `Map<T, List<…>>`, the `T` keys are unique, but when you multi-group into a `Map<T, Map<V, List<…>>>`, the `V` keys are only unique within their sub-map. But depending on your input data structure and actual goal, this might (likely) not be an issue.

Comment: In the Map<T, Map<V, List<?>> case, is each combination of T and V unique? As in, if there is a V1 that appears both at a T1 and a T2, will T2's entry of V1 include the T1 item? I'm not sure if I'm being clear...

Comment: @ElSuscriptorJusticiero: not sure if I get your question correctly, your `V1` is not unique, but `result.get(T1).get(V1)` and `result.get(T2).get(V1)` will return distinct lists containing different items.