# java8 merge two map which structure is Map<String, Map<String, Set<Long>>> in concise

Tags: merge, hashmap, java-8, hashset

Use java8, is there any concise syntax to merge two maps:

```
    Map<String, Map<String, Set<Long>>> m1

    Map<String, Map<String, Set<Long>>> m2
```

And do not change any element in m1, m2, even change the mergedMap.

For example:

the m1 contains 2 elements which like:

```
{
    "k1": {
        "v1": [
            11, 
            12
        ]
    }, 
    "k2": {
        "v2": [
            21
        ]
    }
}
```

the m2 contains 3 elements which like:

```
{
    "k1": {
        "v11": [
            11
        ]
    }, 
    "k2": {
        "v2": [
            21, 
            22
        ]
    }, 
    "k3": {
        "v3": [
            31
        ]
    }
}
```

The merged map what I want is the merged 3 elements.

Especially, the "k1"'s value combine from m1 and m2.

```
{
    "k1": {
        "v1": [
            11, 
            12
        ], 
        "v11": [
            11
        ]
    }, 
    "k2": {
        "v2": [
            21, 
            22
        ]
    }, 
    "k3": {
        "v3": [
            31
        ]
    }
}
```

And when I add some elements in the merged Map which key is <"k3", <"v3", ???>>.

I don't want the origin map m2's elements modify any more.

Comment: Well,   streams may help   - but it is not clear, what exactly you want to be a result?

Comment: I have add an example in my question, thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streams were not meant to be a replacement for everything, so here is my view :

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Set<Long>>> entry : m2.entrySet()) {
        m1.merge(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), (v1, v2) -> {
            for (Map.Entry<String, Set<Long>> e : v2.entrySet()) {
                v1.merge(e.getKey(), e.getValue(), (s1, s2) -> {
                    s1.addAll(s2);
                    return s1;
                });
            }
            return v1;
        });
    }
```

Or using *flatMap* as in the other suggested answer:

```
          Stream.of(m1, m2)
            .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (v1, v2) -> {
                for (Map.Entry<String, Set<Long>> e : v2.entrySet()) {
                    v1.merge(e.getKey(), e.getValue(), (s1, s2) -> {
                        s1.addAll(s2);
                        return s1;
                    });
                }
                return v1;
            }, HashMap::new));
```

Having your input:

```
[k1={v1=[11, 12]}, k2={v2=[21]}]
{k1={v11=[11]}, k2={v2=[21, 22]}, k3={v3=[31]}}
```

Output would be:

```
   {k1={v11=[11], v1=[11, 12]}, k2={v2=[21, 22]}, k3={v3=[31]}}
```

Comment: Well, this *does* modify the source data…

Comment: @Holger did not notice the part about not modifying the input. My bad

Answer (score 4):

Merging nested collections without modifying the source collections is trickier than it might look at the first glance. When performing the merging in-place, modifying one of the source maps, a nested application of `Map.merge` will do, but for collecting the nested data into a new container, a construct similar to the Java 9, [`flatMapping` collector](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) is needed. With this collector, the solution could look like:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Set<Long>>> m3 =
  Stream.concat(m1.entrySet().stream(), m2.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
      flatMapping(e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream(),
        groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, flatMapping(e -> e.getValue().stream(), toSet())))));
```

This also works under Java 8 when using a back-port of the `flatMapping` collector (see the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39131049/2711488)).

An alternative is to create collectors specialized to this use case, considering that the number of `Map`s to merge is rather small:

```
static <T> Collector<Set<T>,?,Set<T>> mergeSets() {
    return Collector.of(HashSet::new, Set::addAll, (s1,s2)->{ s1.addAll(s2); return s1; });
}
static <K,V> Collector<Map<K,V>,?,Map<K,V>> mergeMaps(Collector<V,?,V> c) {
    return collectingAndThen(reducing(
        (m1,m2) -> Stream.concat(m1.entrySet().stream(), m2.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, c)))),
        o -> o.orElse(Collections.emptyMap()));
}
```

These collectors can be combined to do the job:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Set<Long>>> m3 =
    Stream.of(m1, m2).collect(mergeMaps(mergeMaps(mergeSets())));
```

Comment: awesome answer, but your last solution is way too sick. +2 if I could.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of:

```
HashMap<String, Map<String, Set<String>>> m1 = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<String, Map<String, Set<String>>> m2 = new HashMap<>();

Stream.of(m1,m2).flatMap( m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        // stream of entries <String,Set<String>
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue(), (s1, s2) -> { /* do whatever  you like to merge your nested  maps */ return new HashMap<>()}  )
```

`

And of course, you will have to merge nested maps.
This will leave original data structures as they were