# Flat-Mapping Collector for property of a Class using groupingBy

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have this class.

```
class Assignment {
  private Integer index;
  private List<Quantity> quantities;
}
```

Then, I have a list of objects from that class.

```
List<Assigment> assignments = new ArrayList<>();
```

Is there a way to create a `Map` that contains the index from `Assignment` and the `List<Quantity>` as values?

This is what I have tried so far.

```
assignments.stream().collect(groupingBy(Assignment::getIndex));
```

But this gives me a `Map<Integer, List<Assignment>>` and I want a `Map<Integer, List<Quantity>>`.

I have tried using `forEach` method - and it workes - but I'm sure there must be a way to do it in one liner - or at least using only `collect` and `groupingBy` methods

Comment: The established alternative is to use a `flatMap` to a pair type before `collect`. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39131049/2711488). The 3rd alternative would be `.collect(groupingBy(Assignment::getIndex, Collector.of(ArrayList::new, (l,a)->l.addAll(a.getQuantities()), (a,b)->{a.addAll(b); return a; })));`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like there is no flat-mapping collector that you can use as a down-stream for `groupingBy` in Java8, but it has been proposed and accepted for Java9: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8071600

```
public static <T, U, A, R>
    Collector<T, ?, R> flatMapping(Function<? super T, ? extends Stream<? extends U>> mapper,
                                   Collector<? super U, A, R> downstream) {
        BiConsumer<A, ? super U> downstreamAccumulator = downstream.accumulator();
        return Collector.of(downstream.supplier(),
                            (r, t) -> mapper.apply(t).sequential().forEach(u -> downstreamAccumulator.accept(r, u)),
                            downstream.combiner(),
                            downstream.finisher(),
                            downstream.characteristics().stream().toArray(Collector.Characteristics[]::new));
    }
```

---

If you use that one, and also add a `quantities` method to `Assignment` that returns a `Stream<Quantity>`, you can use this code:

```
Map<Integer, List<Quantity>> result = assignments.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Assignment::getIndex, 
        flatMapping(Assignment::quantities, toList())));
```