# Perform flatMap operation with Collectors

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I would like to understand a way to perform a `flatMap` while using `Collector`s. Here is an example.

**Scenario:**

I have the following interfaces:

```
interface Ic {
    //empty
}

interface Ib {
    Stream<Ic> getCs();
}

interface Ia {
    String getName();
    Stream<Ib> getBs();
}
```

And I'm trying to implement the following method:

```
Map<String, Long> total_of_C_per_A (Stream<Ia> streamOfA) {
   return streamOfA.collect(groupBy(Ia::getName, ???));
}
```

The *classification function* is pretty straitforward, my problem is with the *downstream collector*. I need to count the number of "C" associated with "A".

**What I tried to to:**

If I wanted to simply return the count, without creating a map, I would do:

```
streamOfA
  .flatMap(Ia::getBs)
  .flatMap(Ib::getCs)
  .count();
```

But the `Collectors` class only allows me to do *mapping* operations. What else can I try to do?

Thanks.

Comment: This is Java...?

Comment: well there will be a `flatMapping` Collector, but in java-9. Until then... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878646/flat-mapping-collector-for-property-of-a-class-using-groupingby

Comment: Nice effort to produce a minimal example, thanks. Would be even easier to understand (and help) if you could give us compilable code at the same time?

Comment: You `Map` is declared to have `String` keys. Which strings should go in there?

Comment: Sorry for not saying, this is java 8 @Coldspeed

Comment: Thanks for the link @Eugene, it's nice that java 9 might come with this.

Comment: I'll take you advice for future questions @Ole V.V. , thanks for it!

Comment: Eclipse Collections has a `Collector` on the `Collectors2` class called `flatCollect` - https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/8.1.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/collector/Collectors2.html#flatCollect-org.eclipse.collections.api.block.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44749755/2711488) points you already into the right direction, but there is no need to nest multiple `mapping` collectors, as you can just write these functions into a single lambda expression. Considering that the `summingLong` collector expects a function which evaluates to `long`, you can simply pass that function to the collector without any `mapping` collector at all:

```
Map<String, Long> total_of_C_per_A (Stream<Ia> streamOfA) {
    return streamOfA.collect(groupingBy(
            Ia::getName,
            summingLong(ia -> ia.getBs().flatMap(Ib::getCs).count())));
}
```

This also has the advantage that the `long` values are not boxed to `Long` instances.

There’s also an alternative to `flatMap`:

```
Map<String, Long> total_of_C_per_A (Stream<Ia> streamOfA) {
    return streamOfA.collect(groupingBy(
            Ia::getName,
            summingLong(ia -> ia.getBs().mapToLong(ib -> ib.getCs().count()).sum())));
}
```

Comment: I agree on it. :)

Comment: Those two implementations are really helpful and clean. Thanks a lot, it really helped me @Holger !

Answer (score 5):

the documentation described the [Collectors#mapping](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) as:

> Adapts a **Collector** accepting elements of type `U` to one accepting elements of type `T` by applying a mapping function to each input element before accumulation.
>
> The `mapping()` collectors are most useful when used in a **multi-level** reduction, such as downstream of a `groupingBy` or `partitioningBy`.

which means you can composing any possible `Collector`s as you can.

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

Map<String, Long> total_of_C_per_A(Stream<Ia> streamOfA) {
    return streamOfA.collect(groupingBy(
            Ia::getName,
            mapping(
                    Ia::getBs,
                    mapping(
                            it -> it.flatMap(Ib::getCs),
            //    reduce() does boxing & unboxing ---v
                            mapping(Stream::count, reducing(0L,Long::sum))
                    )
            )
    ));
}
```

**OR** using [Collectors#summingLong](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingLong-java.util.function.ToLongFunction-) instead.

```
Map<String, Long> total_of_C_per_A(Stream<Ia> streamOfA) {
    return streamOfA.collect(groupingBy(
            Ia::getName,
            mapping(
                    Ia::getBs,
                    mapping(
                            it -> it.flatMap(Ib::getCs),
            //    summingLong() does boxing      ---v
                            mapping(Stream::count, summingLong(Long::longValue))
            //      Long::longValue does unboxing operation ---^
                    )
            )
    ));
}
```

thanks for @Holger point out the potential problem of the code above, that you can simply using `summingLong(Stream::count)` instead. in this approach is no need to boxing `Stream#count` which return a `long` to a `Long`. and `Long::longValue` unboxing a `Long` to `long`.

```
Map<String, Long> total_of_C_per_A(Stream<Ia> streamOfA) {
    return streamOfA.collect(groupingBy(
        Ia::getName,
        mapping(
            Ia::getBs,
        //    summingLong() doesn't any boxing ---v
            mapping(it -> it.flatMap(Ib::getCs), summingLong(Stream::count))
        )
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @holi-java! I studying the specifics of Java 8 and your answer helped me a lot!

Comment: @Eugene: compared to what? `Collectors.counting()` doesn’t work here, and `reducing(0L,Long::sum)` will still be boxing under Java 9. Note that in this answer, the potential to reduce without boxing hasn’t been exploited anyway, as `mapping(Stream::count,summingLong(Long::longValue))` still boxes all `long` values without any need; it could be simply written as `summingLong(Stream::count)` instead. But without nesting all these `mapping` steps, it becomes even simpler.

Comment: @Eugene: there was in an earlier version. But it doesn’t doesn’t do the intended thing…