# How to merge lists/sets while collecting elements using collectors

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to get product reviews Map based on their name and need a map like

```
Map<String, Set<String>> productReviewMap;
```

but when I try to get the map I am getting

```
Map<String, Set<Set<String>>> productReviewMap
```

based on following code :

```
Map<String, Set<Set<String>>> productReviewMap = products.stream().collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getName, Collectors.mapping(Product::getReviews, Collectors.toSet())));
```

How I can get the expected map. We use flatMap in streams but how can I achieve it in collectors ?

Comment: If you were using Java 9+, I'd opt for [`Collectors#flatMapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector))

Comment: You can use `toMap` collector with merge function. so in merge function merge lists or sets.

Comment: @JacobG thanks,  I am using java 8.  will use toMap

Comment: `products.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Product::getName,v->new HashSet<>(v.getReviews()),(v1,v2)->{v1.addAll(v2);return v1;}));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no built-in collector for this is `JDK8`, so your options are limited:

Use `toMap`:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> resultSet = 
        products.stream()
                .collect(toMap(Product::getName,
                        p -> new HashSet<>(p.getReviews()),
                        (l, r) -> {
                            l.addAll(r);
                            return l;
                        }));
```

or use a custom collector. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878646/flat-mapping-collector-for-property-of-a-class-using-groupingby) and the last code snippet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130122/java-8-nested-multi-level-group-by/39131049#39131049)

`JDK9` has `flatMapping` and can be used as follows:

either this:

```
 Map<String, Set<String>> resultSet = 
        products.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(Product::getName,
                        mapping(Product::getReviews,
                                flatMapping(Collection::stream,
                                        toSet()))));
```

or this:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> resultSet = 
       products.stream()
               .collect(groupingBy(Product::getName,
                        flatMapping(s -> s.getReviews().stream(),toSet())));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this . this would work.
Assuming you are using java 8.

```
Map<String,Set<String>> reviewMap = products.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Product::getName,Product::getReviews));
```

Answer (score -1):

What are the "products" in your code ?

I  made a simple example where products are simply an arrayList, and it works like you want. (i haven implemented a "product" class, so it is simply p -> p

```
List<String> products = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Set<String>> productReviewMap = new HashMap<>();
final Map<String, Set<String>> collect = products.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p, Collectors.mapping(p -> p, Collectors.toSet())));
```

Comment: thanks Vilius, product is POJO which have attr name type String and reviews type Set<String>