# Flattening a list of lists within a map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a stream of orders (the source being a list of orders).
Each order has a Customer, and a list of OrderLine.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a map with the customer as the key, and all order lines belonging to that customer, in a simple list, as value.

What I managed right now returns me a `Map<Customer>, List<Set<OrderLine>>>`, by doing the following:

```
orders
  .collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
      Order::getCustomer,
      Collectors.mapping(Order::getOrderLines, Collectors.toList())
    )
  );
```

I'm either looking to get a `Map<Customer, List<OrderLine>>`directly from the orders stream, or by somehow flattening the list from a stream of the `Map<Customer>, List<Set<OrderLine>>>` that I got above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `Collectors.toMap`.

Something like

```
    orders
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors
                .toMap(Order::getCustomer
                        , Order::getOrderLines
                        , (v1, v2) -> { List<OrderLine> temp = new ArrayList<>(v1); 
                                        temp.addAll(v2); 
                                        return temp;});
```

The third argument to the `toMap` function is the merge function. If you don't explicitly provide that and it there is a duplicate key then it will throw the error while finishing the operation.

Comment: What does this represent, specifically? I understand, you said it's the merge function, but I don't understand how `(v1, v2) -> v2)` works.

Comment: The function says, always take the latest value during merge. For ex: assume you already have an entry in the Map with key "abc" and value "def". If you try to insert the same key "abc" with the value "xyz", this function will make sure the second value is used and not the first value. i.e., "xyz" will be the value that is mapped to key "abc".

Comment: I am just noticing that the list of OrderLine is not complete. This solution doesn't comply with the requirement :(

Comment: You can change the merge function to `(v1, v2) -> { v1.addAll(v2); return v1;}

Comment: This way it works, thx a lot :) And this way I also understand what it is behind

Comment: You could also use `result.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Order::getCustomer, Collectors.flatMapping(o -> order.getOrderLines().stream(), Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Collectors doesn't have a flatMapping function in Java 8

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. I did not notice the question was tagged with java-8

Comment: Using the merge function `(v1, v2) -> { v1.addAll(v2); return v1;}` is dangerous as it will directly manipulate the `Set`s returned by `getOrderLines`, which might be immutable or, even worse, be the internally used sets. The `flatMapping` approach is cleaner and allows to choose between `Set` or `List` or whatever result type you want. At the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39131049/2711488) is a back-port of the `flatMapping` collector, which you can use as drop-in replacement in Java 8. So you only need to adapt the `import static` when switching to Java 9 or newer.

Comment: I agree with Holger on this. Inefficient way to workaround this problem is to create a new list in the merge function like `(v1, v2) -> { mergedList = new ArrayList<>(v1); mergedList.addAll(v2); return mergedList`.

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to use a simple `forEach` call:

```
Map<Customer, List<OrderLine>> map = new HashMap<>();

orders.forEach(
    o -> map.computeIfAbsent(
            o.getCustomer(),
            c -> new ArrayList<OrderLine>()
        ).addAll(o.getOrderLines())
);
```

You can then continue to use streams on the result with `map.entrySet().stream()`.

For a `groupingBy` approach, try [Flat-Mapping Collector for property of a Class using groupingBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878646/flat-mapping-collector-for-property-of-a-class-using-groupingby)

Comment: I would like to avoid forEach calls, in order to be able to proceed with further stream functions, afterwards.