# How to do a groupingBy of groupingBy in java8 with a List attribute inside object

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8

I have

```
class Activity {
    int id;
    ActivityType activityType;
}
class ActivityType {
    int id;
}
class Tournament {
    int id;
    List<Activity> activities;
}
```

I have a

```
List<Tournament> tournaments;
```

And from that I need

```
Map<Tournament, Map<ActivityType, Map<Integer, Activity>>>
```

(where the `Integer` is the `activityId`)

How do I get that using Java 8?

Comment: Yes. Have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the best I was able to come up with java8.

```
Map<Tournament, Map<Activity, Map<Integer, Activity>>> map = tournaments.stream()
           .collect(toMap(identity(),
                          t -> t.getActivities().stream()
                               .collect(groupingBy(A::getActivityType(), 
                                        a -> toMap(A::getId, identity())))));
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the `Map<Integer, Activity>` always contains only one element. In which case it looks more like a `toMap` than a `groupingBy`. Something like:

```
Map<Tournament, Map<Activity, Map<Integer, Activity>>> map = tournaments.stream()
               .collect(toMap(t -> t,
                     t -> t.getActivities().stream().collect(toMap(a -> a, a -> map(a)))));
```

Using this helper method:

```
private static Map<Integer, Activity> map(Activity a) {
  Map<Integer, Activity> m = new HashMap<> ();
  m.put(a.getId(), a);
  return m;
}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid the second stream. Is it possible?

Comment: And the map function can also be replaced with `toMap(a -> a.id, identity())`

Comment: And you can't use toMap in the second collect method, guess toMap is assuming that there are no duplicate keys, and in this case, there could be same activityType for different activities.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a way to get the `Collectors.flatMapping` from jdk-9 (I think it is present in `StreamEx` library), then it could look like this:

```
Stream.of(new Tournament()).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
            Collectors.flatMapping(t -> t.getActivities().stream(), 
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Activity::getActivityType,
                          Collectors.toMap(Activity::getId, Function.identity()))
                    )));
```

**With StreamEx** it could look like this:

```
 Stream.of(new Tournament()).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
            MoreCollectors.flatMapping(t -> t.getActivities().stream(),
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Activity::getActivityType,
                            Collectors.toMap(Activity::getId, Function.identity())))));
```

Comment: Yeah. This would be perfect, but have to live with Java8 :/

Comment: @AswinAlagappan can you bring an additional library like `StreamEx` for example? You might need it for a lot more then just this example...

Comment: @Aswin Alagappan: You don’t have to wait for Java 9 to use `flatMapping`. At the end of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39131049/2711488) is a Java 8 compatible implementation of the `flatMapping` collector which you can copy to your code base, as it’s quiet small. And it’s so straight-forward, that it turned out to be identical to Java 9’s implementation…

Comment: @Eugene: I will try using it. But Java 8 streams itself seems to be slow, is that the same with StreamEx?

Comment: @Holger: Cool !!