# Using groupingBy into a nested Map, but collecting to a different type of object

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, guava

So I have this code that "works" (replacing some names for simplicity):

```
 Map<String, Map<String, ImmutableList<SomeClassA>>> someMap =
      someListOfClassA.stream()
      .filter(...)
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SomeClassA::someCriteriaA,
            Collectors.groupingBy(SomeClassA::someCriteriaB, GuavaCollectors.toImmutableList()
            )
      ));
```

However, I want to change this code so that the inner collection is of SomeClassB after grouping by SomeClassA fields. For example, if the classes look like this:

assuming they both have all args constructors

```
class SomeClassA { 
    String someCriteriaA;
    String someCriteriaB;
    T someData;
    String someId;
}

class SomeClassB {
    T someData;
    String someId; 
}
```

And there's a method somewhere:

```
public static Collection<SomeClassB> getSomeClassBsFromSomeClassA(SomeClassA someA) {
    List<Some List of Class B> listOfB = someMethod(someA);
    return listOfB; // calls something using someClassA, gets a list of SomeClassB 
}
```

I want to flatten the the resulting lists of SomeClass Bs into

```
Map<String, Map<String, ImmutableList<SomeClassB>>> someMap = 
    someListOfClassA.stream()
    .filter(...)
    . // not sure how to group by SomeClassA fields but result in a list of SomeClassB since one SomeClassA can result in multiple SomeClassB
```

I'm not sure how this would fit into the code above. How can I collect a bunch of lists based on SomeClassB into a single list for all the values of SomeClassA? If a single ClassA maps to a single ClassB I know how to get it to work using Collectors.mapping but since each ClassA results in multiple ClassBs I'm not sure how to get it to work.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In Java 9 you'll have [`Collectors.flatMapping()`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-), which will let you flatten the results downstream of the grouping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a custom collector like so:

```
private static Collector<Collection<SomeClassB>, ?, ImmutableList<SomeClassB>>
        flatMapToImmutableList() {
        return Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
                listOfCollectionsOfB ->
                        listOfCollectionsOfB.stream()
                                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                                .collect(GuavaCollectors.toImmutableList()));
    }
```

you can achieve what you're after:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<SomeClassB>>> someMap =
                someListOfClassA.stream()
                        .filter(...)
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SomeClassA::getSomeCriteriaA,
                                Collectors.groupingBy(SomeClassA::getSomeCriteriaB,
                                        Collectors.mapping(a -> getSomeClassBsFromSomeClassA(a),
                                                flatMapToImmutableList()))));
```

Answer (score 3):

While we all wait for Java 9's [`Collectors.flatMapping`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) (thanks to @shmosel for the link), you can write your own collector to achieve what you want:

```
public static <T, D, R> Collector<T, ?, R> flatMapping(
        Function<? super T, ? extends Stream<? extends D>> streamMapper,
        Collector<? super D, ?, R> downstream) {

    class Acc {
        Stream.Builder<Stream<? extends D>> builder = Stream.builder();

        void add(T t) {
            builder.accept(streamMapper.apply(t));
        }

        Acc combine(Acc another) {
            another.builder.build().forEach(builder);
            return this;
        }

        R finish() {
            return builder.build()
                    .flatMap(Function.identity()) // Here!
                    .collect(downstream);
        }
    }
    return Collector.of(Acc::new, Acc::add, Acc::combine, Acc::finish);
}
```

This helper method uses [`Collector.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-) and a local class `Acc` to accumulate the streams returned by the provided `streamMapper` function, which takes an element of the original stream as an argument. These streams are accumulated in a [`Stream.Builder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.Builder.html) that will be built when the collector's finisher function is applied.

Immediately after this stream of streams is built, it is flat-mapped with the identity function, since we only want to concatenate the streams. (I could have used a list of streams instead of a stream of streams, but I think that `Stream.Builder` is both very efficient and highly underused).

`Acc` also implements a combiner method that will merge the given `Acc`'s stream of streams into this `Acc`'s stream builder. This functionality will be used only if the original stream is parallel.

Here's how to use this method with your example:

```
Map<String, Map<String, ImmutableList<SomeClassB>>> map = someListOfClassA.stream()
    .filter(...)
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(SomeClassA::getSomeCriteriaA,
            Collectors.groupingBy(SomeClassA::getSomeCriteriaB,
                flatMapping(
                    a -> getSomeClassBsFromSomeClassA(a).stream(),
                    ImmutableList.toImmutableList()))));
```

---

**EDIT:** As @Holger indicates in the comments below, there's no need for buffering data into a stream builder when accumulating. Instead, a flat-mapping collector can be implemented by performing the flattening right in the accumulator function. [Here is @Holger's own implementation of such collector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130122/java-8-nested-multi-level-group-by/39131049#39131049), which I'm copying here verbatim with his consent:

```
public static <T, U, A, R> Collector<T, ?, R> flatMapping(
        Function<? super T, ? extends Stream<? extends U>> mapper,
        Collector<? super U, A, R> downstream) {

    BiConsumer<A, ? super U> acc = downstream.accumulator();
    return Collector.of(downstream.supplier(),
            (a, t) -> {
                try (Stream<? extends U> s = mapper.apply(t)) {
                    if (s != null) s.forEachOrdered(u -> acc.accept(a, u));
                }
            },
            downstream.combiner(), downstream.finisher(),
            downstream.characteristics().toArray(new Collector.Characteristics[0]));
}
```

Comment: There is no need for buffering data into a builder. A `flatMapping` collector can be implemented by performing the flattening right in the accumulator function. At the end of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39131049/2711488) is such an implementation. It’s not only more efficient, but simpler while also caring about the closing policy. It’s on par (if not identical) to Java 9’s implementation.

Comment: @Holger You are absolutely right, in your version the flat-mapping is implicitly performed when the stream is terminated (by accumulating its elements into the downstream collector). Would you allow me to link to your answer from mine and copy your flat-mapping collector verbatim, making it crystal clear to the reader that the collector is yours?