# Java 8 Streams: Make Collectors.groupingBy return Map<K, List<V>> instead of Map<K, List<List<V>>>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List<SomeBean>`. `SomeBean` contains among others, a method that returns `K` which may be duplicated across the list, and another method that returns `List<V>`. Because of how I'm using `SomeBean`, it's almost analogous to an entry with a key `K` a value `List<V>`.

I want to transform it into a `Map<K, List<V>>`, where `List<V>` is the concatenation of the lists with the same key `K`.
Here is what I have done:

```
private static Map<K, List<V>> transformToMapOfListInTwoSteps(List<SomeBean> paginationResult) {
    Map<K, List<List<V>>> mapOfListOfList = paginationResult.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SomeBean::getK, Collectors.mapping(SomeBean::getV, Collectors.toList())));

    return mapOfListOfList.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> entry.getValue().stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList())));
}
```

However this is currently done in two steps. How can I perform the same operation without using an intermediary throwaway `Map<K, List<List<V>>>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are over complicating things a little bit. I would just use the overload of [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) that accepts a merge function to combine the values when it finds a collision on the keys:

```
private static <K, V> Map<K, List<V>> transformToMapOfListInOneStep(
        List<SomeBean> paginationResult) {

    return paginationResult.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            SomeBean::getK, 
            someBean -> new ArrayList<>(someBean.getV()), 
            (v1, v2) -> { v1.addAll(v2); return v1; }));
}
```

Note: I'm creating a new `ArrayList` within the value mapper function because I don't want to modify the original list that is an attribute of `SomeBean`.

Another approach would be to use `Collectors.groupingBy` along with a downstream collector that flat-maps the values, but this is not implemented in Java 8 (though it will be available in Java 9, see [`Collectors.flatMapping`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-)).

In Java 8, this might be implemented as:

```
public static <T, U, A, R> Collector<T, ?, R> flatMapping(
        Function<? super T, ? extends Stream<? extends U>> mapper,
        Collector<? super U, A, R> downstream) {

    BiConsumer<A, ? super U> acc = downstream.accumulator();
    return Collector.of(downstream.supplier(),
        (a, t) -> {
            try (Stream<? extends U> s = mapper.apply(t)) {
                if (s != null) s.forEachOrdered(u -> acc.accept(a, u));
            }
        },
        downstream.combiner(), downstream.finisher(),
        downstream.characteristics().toArray(new Collector.Characteristics[0]));
}
```

And you could use it this way:

```
return paginationResult.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                SomeBean::getK,
                flatMapping(
                    someBean -> someBean.getV().stream(),
                    Collectors.toList())));
```

Note 2: I've taken the implementation of the `flatMapping` method from [this answer given by user @Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130122/java-8-nested-multi-level-group-by/39131049#39131049).

Comment: Are you sure you want to modify `v1`?

Comment: I really like the first approach when it comes to Java 8! In addition I find it much more readable than my attempt. Also great to know `flatMapping` exists, I was wondering why I couldn't find such a thing when browsing for options in Java 8's Collectors.

Answer (score 1):

Use an additional downstream collector, `collectingAndThen`.

```
private static Map<K, List<V>> transformToMapOfList(List<SomeBean> paginationResult) {
    return paginationResult.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    SomeBean::getK,
                    Collectors.mapping(
                            SomeBean::getV,
                            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                                    Collectors.toList(),
                                    lists -> lists.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList())
                            )
                    )
            ));
}
```

`collectingAndThen` combined with `Collectors.toList()` gives the opportunity to apply a function on the resulting collection, allowing it to be mapped into any type.

---

*I am self-answering as a result of not finding any answer online while trying to figure this out, banging my head for a couple hours while attempting to do some crazy inefficient reduction operations which gave my IDE and compiler severe indigestion.*

[image]

Comment: I feel your pain. It looks like you should have been using `Stream.concat` instead of `Stream.of` in that error message, as well as using [the other reducing collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#reducing-U-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) so that you don't get an `Optional<List<V>>` as the output.

Comment: @4castle Damn it it was `Stream.concat`, I was so close to being inefficient without compile errors. Also I did bang my head on the other reducing collector too prior to writing the post, [as pictured here](http://i.imgur.com/eqkIf1O.png). Still haven't figured them out

Comment: This is incredibly complicated and quite inefficient, since you're still collecting to a `List<List<V>>` and then using a stream to flat-map it to a `List<V>`.

Comment: `Collector.reducing` simply isn’t the right tool when you want a `List` result, for the same reason `Stream.reduce` was supplemented with `Stream.collect`. Following that pattern, you may use a custom collector: `paginationResult.stream() .collect(Collectors.groupingBy( SomeBean::getK, Collector.of(ArrayList::new, (l,bean) -> l.addAll(bean.getV()), (a,b) -> {a.addAll(b);return a;})));`. This is on par with the `flatMapping` solution, it might be even sightly faster, however, `flatMapping` is becoming a builtin collector in Java 9, so it will be the more common idiom for the reader of the code…