# java 8 list grouping with value mapping function producing list

Tags: java-8, grouping, java-stream, flatten

I have a following **Person** class

```
public class Person {

    public String name;

    public List<Brand> brands;

    //Getters
}
```

and a `List<Person> persons`(possibly with same names). I need to group in a map of `<String, List<Brand>>` with Person's `name` as Keys and lists of accumulated `Brands` as values.

Something like this

```
 Map<String, List<List<String>>> collect = list.stream().collect(
        groupingBy(Person::getName, mapping(Person::getBrands, toList()))
 );
```

produces undesired result and I know why. If the values could be somehow flatten during grouping? Is there a way to do it right there with Streams api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing what is the desired result, you can achieve it with just `toMap` collector:

```
Map<String, List<String>> collect = persons.stream().collect(
    toMap(
            Person::getName,
            Person::getBrands,
            (l1, l2) -> ImmutableList.<String /*Brand*/>builder().addAll(l1).addAll(l2).build())
);
```

Answer (score 3):

java 9 will add the [`flatMapping`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) collector specifically for this type of task:

```
list.stream().collect(
    groupingBy(
        Person::getName, 
        flatMapping(
            p -> p.getBrands().stream(), 
            toList()
        )
    )
```

Comment: …and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39131049/2711488) contains the necessary code to be able to use `flatMapping` in Java 8. It’s not that big…

Answer (score 1):

You will need to *merge* brands into a single `List`:

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Person::getName,
            Person::getBrands,
            (left, right) -> {
                left.addAll(right);
                return left;
            },
            HashMap::new));
```

Comment: Warning: This may inadvertently affect the list of brands in one of the `Person` objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom collector for the downstream to your `groupBy`:

```
Collector.of(LinkedList::new, 
            (list, person) -> list.addAll(person.brands), 
            (lhs, rhs) -> { lhs.addAll(rhs); return rhs; })
```

Comment: Any reason for using `LinkedList` here? It’s not only inefficient for most tasks in general, it’s unsuited especially for this specific task.

Answer (score 0):

There is [`MoreCollectors`](https://static.javadoc.io/one.util/streamex/0.6.5/one/util/streamex/MoreCollectors.html#flatMapping-java.util.function.Function-) provided in open source library: [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex)

```
list.stream().collect(
    groupingBy(Person::getName, MoreCollectors.flatMapping(p -> p.getBrands().stream()));
```