# Convert List of List of Elements to Map < K, List<V>>

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I have following structure.

```
Request {
    List<Param> paramList;
    Date startDate;
    Date endDate;
}

Param {
    String paramId;
    List<DataParam> dataParams; 
}

DataParam {
    String dataId;
    List<String> values;
}

CustomRequest {
    List<NewDataParam> newDataParam;
    Date startDate;
    Date endDate;
}

NewDataParam {
 String paramId;
 String dataId;
----
}
```

Iterating over the request with paramList, I want to make map of paramId and generated request like `Map<String, List<CustomRequest>>`.

With following code, I got `Map<String, List<List<CustomRequest>>>`. Can someone suggest how to get `Map<String, List<CustomRequest>>`.

```
request.paramList().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Param::getParamId, 
        Collectors.mapping(i -> i.dataParams().stream()
           .map(r -> customBuildMethod(i.dataParamId(), r, request)).collect(Collectors.toList()), Collectors.toList())));

private CustomRequest customBuildMethod(String paramId ...) {
    CustomRequest customRequest = new CustomRequest();
    //mapping
    return customRequest;
}
```

Comment: In your end result i.e. tha map `Map<String, List<CustomRequest>>` what is the key here? is it NewDataParam::paramid ?

Comment: Param::paramId is the key, it is same as NewDataParam::paramid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use Java 9, you can achieve your goal with [Collectors.flatMapping](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-):

```
request.paramList()
       .stream()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Param::getParamId, 
                                      Collectors.flatMapping(i -> i.dataParams().stream().map(r -> customBuildMethod(i.dataParamId(), r, request))), 
                                                            Collectors.toList())));
```

In Java 8, you can do the following:

```
Map<String, List<CustomRequest>> result = 
    request.paramList()
          .stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Param::getParamId, 
                                         Collector.of(ArrayList::new, 
                                                     (l,i)->l.addAll(i.dataParams().stream().map(r -> customBuildMethod(i.dataParamId(), r, request)).collect(Collectors.toList())),
                                                     (l1,l2)->{l1.addAll(l2);return l1;})));
```

Comment: I can not use java9 yet. Is there no way we can achieve this with java8?

Comment: @Amit I made a Java 8 attempt. I hope I have no typos, since I couldn't check this code.

Comment: @Amit you can use `flatMapping` in Java 8 too. You will find the necessary code at the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39131049/2711488); it’s just twelve lines of code…

Comment: Thank you. It is very interesting solution.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `Collectors.mapping()` you can use `Collectors.collectingAndThen()` where in finisher function you can do a flatMap using list of data params. Something like that:

```
Map<String, List<CustomRequest>> map = params.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Param::getParamId, Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), it -> it.stream()
                        .flatMap(i -> i.getDataParams().stream())
                        .map(r -> new CustomRequest(Arrays.asList(new NewDataParam()), new Date(), new Date()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
                ))
        );

System.out.println(map);
```

Full example I used for tests:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ListOfListsToMapOfStringAndListExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final List<Param> params = Arrays.asList(
                new Param("1", Arrays.asList(new DataParam("2", Arrays.asList("a", "b")))),
                new Param("3", Arrays.asList(new DataParam("4", Arrays.asList("c", "d")))),
                new Param("5", Arrays.asList(new DataParam("6", Arrays.asList("e", "f"))))
        );

        Map<String, List<CustomRequest>> map = params.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Param::getParamId, Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), it -> it.stream()
                                .flatMap(i -> i.getDataParams().stream())
                                .map(r -> new CustomRequest(Arrays.asList(new NewDataParam()), new Date(), new Date()))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                        ))
                );

        System.out.println(map);
    }


    static class Request {
        List<Param> paramList;
        Date startDate;
        Date endDate;

        public Request(List<Param> paramList, Date startDate, Date endDate) {
            this.paramList = paramList;
            this.startDate = startDate;
            this.endDate = endDate;
        }
    }

    static class Param {
        String paramId;
        List<DataParam> dataParams;

        public Param(String paramId, List<DataParam> dataParams) {
            this.paramId = paramId;
            this.dataParams = dataParams;
        }

        public String getParamId() {
            return paramId;
        }

        public List<DataParam> getDataParams() {
            return dataParams;
        }
    }

    static class DataParam {
        String dataId;
        List<String> values;

        public DataParam(String dataId, List<String> values) {
            this.dataId = dataId;
            this.values = values;
        }

        public String getDataId() {
            return dataId;
        }

        public List<String> getValues() {
            return values;
        }
    }

    static class CustomRequest {
        List<NewDataParam> newDataParam;
        Date startDate;
        Date endDate;

        public CustomRequest(List<NewDataParam> newDataParam, Date startDate, Date endDate) {
            this.newDataParam = newDataParam;
            this.startDate = startDate;
            this.endDate = endDate;
        }

        public List<NewDataParam> getNewDataParam() {
            return newDataParam;
        }

        public Date getStartDate() {
            return startDate;
        }

        public Date getEndDate() {
            return endDate;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "CustomRequest{" +
                    "newDataParam=" + newDataParam +
                    ", startDate=" + startDate +
                    ", endDate=" + endDate +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    static class NewDataParam {

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "NewDataParam{}";
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{1=[CustomRequest{newDataParam=[NewDataParam{}], startDate=Wed Feb 14 09:03:21 CET 2018, endDate=Wed Feb 14 09:03:21 CET 2018}], 3=[CustomRequest{newDataParam=[NewDataParam{}], startDate=Wed Feb 14 09:03:21 CET 2018, endDate=Wed Feb 14 09:03:21 CET 2018}], 5=[CustomRequest{newDataParam=[NewDataParam{}], startDate=Wed Feb 14 09:03:21 CET 2018, endDate=Wed Feb 14 09:03:21 CET 2018}]}
```

#### Update:

In case of passing `param.paramId` to `customBuildMethod` you can even get rid of `flatMap()` on`param.dataParams` and map your initial param object to a `CustomRequest`. Something like:

```
Map<String, List<CustomRequest>> map = params.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Param::getParamId, Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), it -> it.stream()
                        .map(param -> customBuildMethod(param.paramId, param.dataParams))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
                ))
        );
```

In this example I pass `param.paramId` and `param.dataParams` to this helper method which creates `CustomRequest` object. It can use a list of data params to create a new list of new data params objects:

```
private static CustomRequest customBuildMethod(String paramId, List<DataParam> params) {
    return new CustomRequest(
            params.stream().map(dataParam -> new NewDataParam()).collect(Collectors.toList()),
            new Date(),
            new Date()
    );
}
```

Or more directly according to your code:

```
Map<String, List<CustomRequest>> map = params.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Param::getParamId, Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), it -> it.stream()
                        .map(param -> customBuildMethod(param.paramId, r, request))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
                ))
        );
```

Comment: Thank you for such detailed explanation. If you see my customBuild method, I need to pass the paramId to make `NewDataParam` in customRequest. How can we pass that information in `i` to custom method.

Comment: @Amit In this case things can be simplified and you get skip flatMap part and map param directly to custom request object. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you , I accepted above answer from Eran because I do not need to modify my existing customMethod. Your solution is also good. thank you