# Elegant way to flatMap Set of Sets inside groupingBy

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

So I have a piece of code where I'm iterating over a list of data. Each one is a `ReportData` that contains a case with a `Long caseId` and one `Ruling`. Each `Ruling` has one or more `Payment`. I want to have a `Map` with the `caseId` as keys and sets of payments as values (i.e. a `Map<Long, Set<Payments>>`).

Cases are not unique across rows, but cases are.

In other words, I can have several rows with the same case, but they will have unique rulings.

The following code gets me a `Map<Long, Set<Set<Payments>>>` which is almost what I want, but I've been struggling to find the correct way to flatMap the final set in the given context. I've been doing workarounds to make the logic work correctly using this map as is, but I'd very much like to fix the algorithm to correctly combine the set of payments into one single set instead of creating a set of sets.

I've searched around and couldn't find a problem with the same kind of iteration, although flatMapping with Java streams seems like a somewhat popular topic.

```
rowData.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            r -> r.case.getCaseId(),
            Collectors.mapping(
                r -> r.getRuling(),
                Collectors.mapping(ruling->
                    ruling.getPayments(),
                    Collectors.toSet()
                )
            )));
```

Comment: Are the caseIds unique in the list of `ReportData`?

Comment: No, they are not unique. The input data contains duplicate cases but they all have unique rulings for that specific case. So you could argue the input data is not ideal :P

Comment: Could you provide the code of the involved classes? (`ReportData`, `Ruling`, `Payment`) This will make very clear what each one is. Also, the code you provided clearly does not compile: there is a `case` field that is referenced (reserved keyword), and it seems `r.getRulings()` should be `r.getRuling()`.

Comment: @DidierL you're right, I edited getRulings() to getRuling(). As for the case, I just quickly translated the field names (we don't use english for field names etc. in this project). You're right, it is a reserved keyword and that wouldn't be allowed.

Comment: Next time, you should provide a [mcve]. Here I had to guess all your class structures from what I understood of your question to be able to work in my IDE. I think @marstran just wrote the answer inline but thus he was certainly not able to validate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another JDK8 solution:

```
Map<Long, Set<Payment>> resultSet = 
         rowData.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.Case.getCaseId(),
                        p -> new HashSet<>(p.getRuling().getPayments()),
                        (l, r) -> { l.addAll(r);return l;}));
```

or as of JDK9 you can use the `flatMapping` collector:

```
rowData.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r -> r.Case.getCaseId(), 
              Collectors.flatMapping(e -> e.getRuling().getPayments().stream(), 
                        Collectors.toSet())));
```

Comment: @DidierL yup true, given the previous edit. a bit rusty with Java lately. thanks.

Comment: You should keep the `new HashSet()` wrapper however, otherwise you are modifying the ruling's payments in the source collection.

Comment: @DidierL Right, will keep it then. ;-)

Comment: This seems to be the way to go

Comment: …and if you are still forced to use Java 8, you’ll find a Java 8 compatible implementation of the `flatMapping` collector at the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39131049/2711488). Since it has the same signature, it is easy to migrate from that solution to the standard API version in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest solution is to define your own collector:

```
Map<Long, Set<Payment>> result = rowData.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                ReportData::getCaseId,
                Collector.of(HashSet::new,
                        (s, r) -> s.addAll(r.getRuling().getPayments()),
                        (s1, s2) -> { s1.addAll(s2); return s1; })
        ));
```

---

Two other solutions to which I thought first but are actually less efficient and readable, but still avoid constructing the intermediate `Map`:

Merging the inner sets using `Collectors.reducing()`:

```
Map<Long, Set<Payment>> result = rowData.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                ReportData::getCaseId,
                Collectors.reducing(Collections.emptySet(),
                        r -> r.getRuling().getPayments(),
                        (s1, s2) -> {
                            Set<Payment> r = new HashSet<>(s1);
                            r.addAll(s2);
                            return r;
                        })
        ));
```

where the `reducing` operation will merge the `Set<Payment>` of entries with the same `caseId`. This can however cause a lot of copies of the sets if you have a lot of merges needed.

Another solution is with a downstream collector that flatmaps the nested collections:

```
Map<Long, Set<Payment>> result = rowData.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                ReportData::getCaseId,
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.mapping(r -> r.getRuling().getPayments(), Collectors.toList()),
                        s -> s.stream().flatMap(Set::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet())))
        );
```

Basically it puts all sets of matching `caseId` together in a `List`, then flatmaps that list into a single `Set`.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably better ways to do this, but this is the best I found:

```
 Map<Long, Set<Payment>> result =
            rowData.stream()
                    // First group by caseIds.
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r -> r.case.getCaseId()))
                    .entrySet().stream()
                    // By streaming over the entrySet, I map the values to the set of payments.
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            Map.Entry::getKey,
                            entry -> entry.getValue().stream()
                                    .flatMap(r -> r.getRuling().getPayments().stream())
                                    .collect(Collectors.toSet())));
```

Comment: Oh ops I realized I gave wrong information now. There's only one Ruling per row actually. I messed up because the input data itself contains duplicates of cases but only one case and one ruling per dataRow. So sorry!

Comment: @LarsHoldaas Ok, I edited the answer to only have one ruling per case. The idea should be the same, right?

Comment: Oh yeah! This seems to work like a charm! Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Look at @Aomine's answer for a better solution if you're on Java 9. By using the `flatMapping` collector, you no longer need the immediate map from `groupingBy`-