# Java 8 Stream API - Java 9 Collectors.flatMapping rewritten in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, java-9, collectors

I got in touch with a new feature since [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9) called [`Collectors.flatMapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) that takes place as a downstream of grouping or partitioning. Such as (example taken from [here](https://www.logicbig.com/how-to/code-snippets/jcode-java-8-streams-collectors-flatmapping.html)):

```
List<List<Integer>> list = Arrays.asList(
    Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
    Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9, 10));

Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map =list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
         Collection::size,
         Collectors.flatMapping(
             l -> l.stream().filter(i -> i % 2 == 0),
             Collectors.toList())));
```

> {4=[8, 10], 6=[2, 4, 6]}

This is a fairly elegant way using just **3** collectors. I need to rewrite the collector in [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) where is not yet supported. My attempt use  **6** Collectors that is quite an extensive usage and I am not able to figure out a way using less of them:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Collection::size,
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.mapping(
                l -> l.stream().filter(i -> i % 2 == 0).collect(Collectors.toList()),
                Collectors.toList()),
            i -> i.stream().flatMap(j -> j.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList()))));
```

Is there a <strike>shorter</strike> better way using solely [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)?

Comment: @Michael agreed, you should post a version of this back-port actually, would be glad to upvote. I thought there would be already one by Holger, but I can't find it on stack overflow...

Comment: [found it...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130122/java-8-nested-multi-level-group-by/39131049#39131049)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For just *this* particular case, I guess this would be a simpler version:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map =
        list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Collection::size,
                x -> x.stream().filter(y -> y % 2 == 0).collect(Collectors.toList())
            ));
```

If there would be merging involved (two collections that would have the same size), I would add a `merge` function that is pretty trivial:

```
 Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map =
        list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Collection::size,
                x -> x.stream().filter(y -> y % 2 == 0).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)),
                (left, right) -> {
                    left.addAll(right);
                    return left;
                }
            ));
```

Otherwise, I agree with Michael in this comment, this is not that hard to back-port to java-8.

Answer (score 19):

I would just backport `flatMapping`. It only requires 2 methods and 1 class, with no other dependencies.

Also, when it comes time to upgrade to Java 9, you can just deprecate your version and replace any usages of it with the proper version.

[The following code is taken from the JDK](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/65464a307408/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#l449). I didn't write it. I have tested it with your example and it returns the same result.

```
class Nikollectors
{
   public static <T, U, A, R> Collector<T, ?, R> flatMapping(Function<? super T, ? extends Stream<? extends U>> mapper, Collector<? super U, A, R> downstream) {
        BiConsumer<A, ? super U> downstreamAccumulator = downstream.accumulator();
        return new CollectorImpl<>(downstream.supplier(),
            (r, t) -> {
                try (Stream<? extends U> result = mapper.apply(t)) {
                    if (result != null)
                        result.sequential().forEach(u -> downstreamAccumulator.accept(r, u));
                }
            },
            downstream.combiner(), downstream.finisher(),
            downstream.characteristics());
    }

   private static class CollectorImpl<T, A, R> implements Collector<T, A, R>
   {
        private final Supplier<A> supplier;
        private final BiConsumer<A, T> accumulator;
        private final BinaryOperator<A> combiner;
        private final Function<A, R> finisher;
        private final Set<Characteristics> characteristics;

        CollectorImpl(Supplier<A> supplier,
                      BiConsumer<A, T> accumulator,
                      BinaryOperator<A> combiner,
                      Function<A,R> finisher,
                      Set<Characteristics> characteristics) {
            this.supplier = supplier;
            this.accumulator = accumulator;
            this.combiner = combiner;
            this.finisher = finisher;
            this.characteristics = characteristics;
        }

        CollectorImpl(Supplier<A> supplier,
                      BiConsumer<A, T> accumulator,
                      BinaryOperator<A> combiner,
                      Set<Characteristics> characteristics) {
            this(supplier, accumulator, combiner, castingIdentity(), characteristics);
        }

        @Override
        public BiConsumer<A, T> accumulator() {
            return accumulator;
        }

        @Override
        public Supplier<A> supplier() {
            return supplier;
        }

        @Override
        public BinaryOperator<A> combiner() {
            return combiner;
        }

        @Override
        public Function<A, R> finisher() {
            return finisher;
        }

        @Override
        public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
            return characteristics;
        }
    }

   private static <I, R> Function<I, R> castingIdentity() {
       return i -> (R) i;
   }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map =list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
         Collection::size,
         Nikollectors.flatMapping( // <<<
             l -> l.stream().filter(i -> i % 2 == 0),
             Collectors.toList()
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: you deserve two upvotes for `Nikollectors`... you should add an example of the usage too and may be a static factory method that would return this `Collectors::flatMapping` to make it a full example IMHO

Comment: you might be joking, but in my project we have a package `xxx.HolgerUtil` - just to be sure where this was taken from, no joke. :)

Comment: I'm stuck in java 8 and this is the answer I didn't realize I was looking for. Thanks!