# How to collect in Map<String, Arraylist<String>> in list of fields in list of object?

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, java-8, stream

I have a AssistantList and need to map to Map of
(Key - Assistant Login,
Value - ArrayList of its Supervisor)

I used below code to map using for loop.

How can I use stream api to achieve the same functionality,

```
  for(Assistant assistant: assistantList)
  {
      for(Supervisor supervisor: assistant.getSupervisorList())
      {
              map.computeIfAbsent(assistant.getLogin(), k->new ArrayList<>()).add(supervisor.getLogin());
      }
  }
```

Thank you

Comment: I think current way is more readable. BTW  java stream version like this: `assistantList.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(Assistant::getLogin,
                        Collectors.mapping(Assistant::getSupervisorList,
                                Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), lists ->
                                        lists.stream().flatMap(List::stream).map(Supervisor::getLogin).collect(Collectors.toList())))));`

Comment: I’d rather use `for(Assistant assistant: assistantList) { List<…> l = map.computeIfAbsent(assistant.getLogin(), k->new ArrayList<>()); for(Supervisor supervisor: assistant.getSupervisorList()) l.add(supervisor.getLogin()); }`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use combination of `groupBy` for grouping and `flatMapping` for merging the supervisors:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.flatMapping;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

Map<String, List<String>> grouped = assistantList.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(
                Assistant::getLogin,
                flatMapping(
                        assistant -> assistant.getSupervisorList()
                                .stream()
                                .map(Supervisor::getLogin),
                        toList())
        ));
    }
}
```

Also I think `Map<String, Set<String>>` could work better, to remove possible supervisor duplicate values.

`flatMapping` is `Java 9+` collector, for Java 8 you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54287457/java-8-stream-api-java-9-collectors-flatmapping-rewritten-in-java-8) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130122/java-8-nested-multi-level-group-by/39131049#39131049) answers on possible alternatives.

Comment: java 8 version like this: `assistantList.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(Assistant::getLogin,
                        Collectors.mapping(Assistant::getSupervisorList,
                                Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), lists ->
                                        lists.stream().flatMap(List::stream).map(Supervisor::getLogin).collect(Collectors.toList())))));`

Comment: I’d rather use the `flatMapping` implementation shown at the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39131049/2711488) in Java 8.

Comment: Thx, looks good, I added ref to this answer as well