# How to convert List<Object> to Map<Integer,Set<Set<String>> in Java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream, hashset

```
    class Employee{
      private Integer employeeId;
      private Integer projectId;
      private String mobileNumbers;
    }
```

I want to convert List of employees to Map of projectId & mobile numbers. Mobile numbers can have multiple values comma separated(eg: mobileNumbers="7364567347,5784345445")

I want to split mobile number with partition of 100. Hence the value datatype is Set<Set>

Two things which I am not able to achieve in Java 8 using stream
1.Not able to split multiple mobileNumber as individual element in Set object.
2.Not able to partition

Eg:

```
  Employee[employeeId=1,projectId=1,mobileNumbers="1111,2222"]
  Employee[employeeId=2,projectId=1,mobileNumbers="33333"]
  Employee[employeeId=3,projectId=2,mobileNumbers="44444,5555"]
```

Expected :
{1=[["1111","2222","33333"]], 2=[["44444","5555"]]}

I am able to proceed till Map<ProjectId,Set>. I am not able to split mobileNumbers

```
Map<Integer,Set<String>> result2=employeeList.stream()
         .collect(
          Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getProjectId,
              Collectors.mapping(Employee::getMobileNumbers, Collectors.toSet()))
      );
```

Two things which I am not able to achieve in Java 8 using stream
1.Not able to split multiple mobileNumber as individual element in Set object.
2.Not able to partition `

Comment: The groupBy looks pretty much correct. All you need to do now is split the phone numbers (try using `String.split`) and then combining the collection of arrays into one set (probably using some kind of `flatMap`)

Answer (score 1):

As always with this type of question, the imperative approach is much easier to read and reason about:

```
        Map<Integer, Set<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
        for (Employee employee : employeeList) {
            Set<String> set = result.result.computeIfAbsent(employee.getProjectId(), id -> new HashSet<>());
            set.addAll(Arrays.asList(employee.getMobileNumbers().split(",")));
        }
```

Once you understand this approach, you may even be able to turn it into a functional pipeline. But if you want this code to be maintainable, you probably shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

To use streams only, you need the [flatMapping](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) method, which was not added until Java 9.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54287457/java-8-stream-api-java-9-collectors-flatmapping-rewritten-in-java-8) has a starting point, and then you need code like this:

```
Map<Integer,Set<String>> result2 = employeeList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Employee::getProjectId,
        flatMapping(
            e -> Arrays.stream(e.getMobileNumbers().split(",")),
            Collectors.toSet())));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the grouped values and flatmap into `Set` in the downstream collector:

```
Map<Integer, Set<String>> result2 = employeeList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getProjectId,
        Collectors.mapping(Employee::getMobileNumbers,
            Collectors.flatMapping(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(",")), 
                Collectors.toSet()))));
```

> ```
> {1=[33333, 1111, 2222], 2=[44444, 5555]}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to have a `Map<Integer, Set<Set<String>>>`, and not a `Map<Integer, Set<String>>` as in the previous solutions.
In my opinion, making the partitions using `Streams` makes the code illegible. Thus, I'd resort to an additional function to check the set conditions.
To construct the example, I chose three as the maximum number of elements in a set, so you must adjust the answer according to your needs.

```
   final List<Employee> employees = Arrays.asList(
                new Employee(1, 1, "1111,2222"),
                new Employee(2, 1, "33333,4444"),
                new Employee(3, 2, "44444,5555")
        );

        final Map<Integer, Set<Set<String>>> idToNumberPartitions = employees.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Employee::getProjectId,
                        Collector.of(
                                HashSet::new,
                                (set, employee) -> addNumbersToPartition(set, employee.getMobileNumbers().split(",")),
                                (set1, set2) -> {
                                    set1.addAll(set2);
                                    return set1;
                                }
                        )
                ));


    }

    private static void addNumbersToPartition(final Set<Set<String>> allSets, final String[] numbers) {
        Set<String> currentSet = null;
        for (final String number : numbers) {
            if (currentSet == null || currentSet.size() >= 3) {
                currentSet = new HashSet<>();
                allSets.add(currentSet);
            }
            currentSet.add(number);
        }
    }
}
```

For the example above, this prints:

```
{1=[[1111, 2222], [33333, 4444]], 2=[[44444, 5555]]}
```

Consult the docs to find out more about the custom Collector:

```
    public static<T, R> Collector<T, R, R> of(Supplier<R> supplier,
                                              BiConsumer<R, T> accumulator,
                                              BinaryOperator<R> combiner,
                                              Characteristics... characteristics)
```