# Optional[value] is getting printed

Tags: java, functional-programming, underscore-java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    printSumOfAllNumbersInList(List.of(12,45,34,22,56,65));
    printSumOfAllNumbersInListUsingFP(List.of(12,45,34,22,56,65));
}

private static void printSumOfAllNumbersInListUsingFP(List<Integer> list) {
    
    /*
     * Learning the use of reduce()
     */
    System.out.println(list.stream().reduce(PStructured01::printSum));
    
}

private static int printSum(int a,int b)
{
    int sum  =  a +b;
    return sum;
            
            
}
private static void printSumOfAllNumbersInList(List<Integer> list) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Integer integer: list) {
        sum = sum + integer;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}}
```

I am solving the Use Case - Print the sum of all list numbers and return the sum.
I tried using the traditional approach and later tried to solve it using the Functional Approach.
But during the Functional Approach, I am getting the value - 234 as correct but as - Optional[234]
Can some one please explain the reason

Comment: What do you think the return type of `Stream.reduce` is?

Comment: So how do we handle it?

Comment: I'm sure figuring that out is part of the assignment. Just take a look at the docs for that type, it's pretty simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce, in this case, returns an [OptionalInt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/OptionalInt.html) and to retrieve it you need to use `OptionalInt.getAsInt()`.  You could also do it like this.

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(12,45,34,22,56,65);
int sum = list.stream().mapToInt(a->a).sum();
System.out.println(sum);
```

prints

```
234
```

Comment: Users with your rep should know better than to just give away the solution to homework questions

Comment: @Jorn I did not see the word homework in the question.  Nor am I psychic.

Comment: @jorn  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76464455/how-to-convert-listobject-to-mapinteger-setsetstring-in-java-8-stream) looks like a homework question to me.  But I am not going to downvote you for answering it since that is just my opinion.   And you're not psychic either.

Comment: Hey this is not a homework question. I am visiting Java 8 new feature for the first time. That's why asked for the help

Comment: @AshikaJinturkar Thank you for pointing that out and making my case.

Comment: You could also use the "identity" function for unboxing an integer: `.mapToInt(Integer::intValue)`, rather than an arrow function.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl  True.  And it is more descriptive.  But I just do `a->a` out of habit.

Answer (score 1):

I did this over my research, firstly thought its bit ununderstood but it was an easy concept

```java
Optional<Integer> op = list.stream().reduce(PStructured01::printSum);

op.ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I've added an answer that removes the optional completely. There's no need to call `ifPresent`, which will do nothing if you pass an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using this overload of `reduce` that returns an `Optional<Integer>`<sup>1</sup>, use the overload that takes an identity element. If the list is empty, this identity element will be returned:

```java
System.out.println(list.stream().reduce(0, PStructured01::printSum));
```

<sup>1</sup> Since the source is `List<Integer>` and the stream is nowhere mapped to an `IntStream`, the result cannot be an `OptionalInt`.