# Is there a way to concatenate grouped lists into a set in Java 8 in one line?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm in a weird situation where have a JSON API that takes an array with strings of neighborhoods as keys and an array of strings of restaurants as values which get GSON-parsed into the Restaurant object (defined with a `String` for the neighborhood and a `List<String>` with the restaurants). The system stores that data in a map whose keys are the neighborhood names and values are a set of restaurant names in that neighborhood. Therefore, I want to implement a function that takes the input from the API, groups the values by neighborhood and concatenates the lists of restaurants.

Being constrained by Java 8, I can't use more recent constructs such as *flatMapping* to do everything in one line and the best solution I've found is this one, which uses an intermediate map to store a Set of List before concatenating those lists into a Set to be store as value in the final map:

```
public Map<String, Set<String>> parseApiEntriesIntoMap(List<Restaurant> restaurants) {
    if(restaurants == null) {
      return null;
    }
    Map<String, Set<String>> restaurantListByNeighborhood = new HashMap<>();
    // Here we group by neighborhood and concatenate the list of restaurants into a set
    Map<String, Set<List<String>>> map =
        restaurants.stream().collect(groupingBy(Restaurant::getNeighborhood,
                              Collectors.mapping(Restaurant::getRestaurantList, toSet())));
    map.forEach((n,r) -> restaurantListByNeighborhood.put(n, Sets.newHashSet(Iterables.concat(r))));

    return restaurantListByNeighborhood;
  }
```

I feel like there has to be a way do get rid of that intermediate map and do everything in one line...does someone have a better solution that would allow me to do this?

Comment: Note that neither "one line" nor "using streams" means "better". There is nothing wrong with an old-school loop. Also, if `getRestaurantList()` returns the names of individual restaurants of a restaurant chain, it seems overkill, since it would be exceedingly rare to find more than 1 instance of a chain in a given neighbourhood, and thus a better model would be the have a `chain` attribute on `Restaurant` is you really care and simply have each instance of a `Restaurant` have its own entry. If not, then what does it mean? Should `Restaurant` be renamed `RestaurantChain` for clarity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could with Java-8 simply use `toMap` with a `mergeFunction` defined as:

```
public Map<String, Set<String>> parseApiEntriesIntoMap(List<Restaurant> restaurants) {
    // read below about the null check
    return restaurants.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Restaurant::getNeighborhood,
                    r -> new HashSet<>(r.getRestaurantList()), (set1, set2) -> {
                        set1.addAll(set2);
                        return set1;
                    }));
}
```

---

Apart from which, one should ensure that the check and the result from the first block of code from your method

```
if(restaurants == null) {
  return null;
}
```

when on the other hand dealing with *empty* `Collection`s and `Map`, it should be redundant as the above code would return empty Map for an empty List by the nature of stream and collect operation itself.

*Note*: Further, if you may require a much relatable code to `flatMapping` in your future upgrades, you can use the implementation provided [in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130122/java-8-nested-multi-level-group-by/39131049#39131049)

---

Or a solution without using streams, in this case, would look similar to the approach using `Map.merge`. It would use a similar `BiFunction` as:

```
public Map<String, Set<String>> parseApiEntriesIntoMap(List<Restaurant> restaurants) {
    Map<String, Set<String>> restaurantListByNeighborhood = new HashMap<>();
    for (Restaurant restaurant : restaurants) {
        restaurantListByNeighborhood.merge(restaurant.getNeighborhood(),
                new HashSet<>(restaurant.getRestaurantList()),
                (strings, strings2) -> {
                    strings.addAll(strings2);
                    return strings;
                });
    }
    return restaurantListByNeighborhood;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I didn't realize I could use `Map.merge` also to group by neighborhood and that the null check wasn't necessary.

Comment: @creposukre The null check wouldn't be necessary when the `List` passed to the method is ensured to be either empty or filled with values, which shall be a general practice while using Collections (saves one from unwanted null checks and NPEs.)

Comment: I’d rather use `restaurantListByNeighborhood.computeIfAbsent(restaurant.getNeighborhood(), key -> new HashSet<>()).addAll(restaurant.getRestaurantList());` in the loop… and since you mentioned the `flatMapping`, it would have been nice to also mention the complete solution, i.e. `restaurants.stream().collect(groupingBy(Restaurant::getNeighborhood, flatMapping(r -> r.getRestaurantList().stream(), toSet())));`, as I did see it in this Q&A yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can also flatten the `Set<List<String>>` after collecting them using `Collectors.collectingAndThen`

```
Map<String, Set<String>> res1 = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Restaurant::getNeighborhood,
            Collectors.mapping(Restaurant::getRestaurantList, 
                    Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toSet(), 
                            set->set.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet())))));
```

Comment: Why would you introduce `joining` here? That would end up joining all the elements of one collection into a single string and then add other such occurrences into a final Set.

Comment: `Sets.newHashSet(Iterables.concat(r))` flattens the `Set<List<String>>` to `Set<Sting>` but not by joining the Strings of the List within. e.g. `Set.of(List.of("one", "two"), List.of("three","four"))` would turn into `Set.of("one", "two","three","four")` and *not*  something like `Set.of("one two", "three four")`.

Comment: Yes, I meant flattening the `Set<List<String>>` into a `Set<String>` with the elements of the lists within the set being extracted out of that list and becoming elements of the Set

Comment: Nice! This is the solution I was looking for, thank you! I was thinking of using `Collectors.collectingAndThen` but couldn't wrap my head around how to use it to achieve the desired outcome