# How to use groupingBy of stream API for multi level nested classes?

Tags: collections, java-stream

I have a list of `Student` objects `List<Student> allStudents` from which I need to find out which student gained how much score per course and task using Java 8 stream API. I came across some older posts like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130122/java-8-nested-multi-level-group-by) but couldn't apply to my problem.

Below are my nested classes:

```
public class Student{
    private long studentId;
    private List<Course> courses;

    public long getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public List<Course> getCourses() {
        return courses;
    }
}

public class Course{
    private long courseId;
    private List<Task> tasks;

    public long getCourseId() {
        return courseId;
    }

    public List<Task> getTasks() {
        return tasks;
    }
}

public class Task{
    private long taskId;
    private List<Assessment> assessments;

    public long getTaskId() {
        return taskId;
    }

    public List<Assessment> getAssessments() {
        return assessments;
    }
}

public class Assessment{
    private String type;
    private double score;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public double getScore() {
        return score;
    }
}
```

Somehow multi level grouping couldn't work for me. Could anyone guide me on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in the old question you referenced, can use the flat map approach where each nesting level is flat mapped down to the level required as follows:

```
    Map<Triple<Long, Long, Long>, Double> result = allStudents.stream()
            .flatMap(s -> s.getCourses().stream().map(
                    c -> ImmutableTuple.of(s.getStudentId(), c)))
            .flatMap(sc -> sc.get().getTasks().stream().map(
                    t -> ImmutableTuple.of(sc.getFirst(), sc.get().getCourseId(), t)))
            .flatMap(sct -> sct.get().getAssessments().stream().map(
                    a -> ImmutableTuple.of(sct.getFirst(), sct.getSecond(), sct.get().taskId, a.getScore())))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    ImmutableQuadruple::remove,
                    Collectors.summingDouble(ImmutableQuadruple::get)
            ));
```

Note: This is using tuples from the typedtuples library