# How to identify duplicate records in a list?

Tags: java, lambda, partitioning

I have the following problem:

I want to remove duplicate data from a list of a Vo depending if the registered field is the same, I show you the solution that I am trying. Then this is the data from the list that I am making

```
List<MyVo> dataList = new ArrayList<MyVo>();

MyVo  data1 = new MyVo();
data1.setValidated(1);
data1.setName("Fernando");
data1.setRegistered("008982");

MyVo data2 = new MyVo();
data2.setValidated(0);
data2.setName("Orlando");
data2.setRegistered("008986");

MyVo data3 = new MyVo();
data3.setValidated(1);
data3.setName("Magda");
data3.setRegistered("008982");


MyVo data4 = new MyVo();
data4.setValidated(1);
data4.setName("Jess");
data4.setRegistered("006782");

dataList.add(data1);
dataList.add(data2);
dataList.add(data3);
dataList.add(data4);
```

The first thing I have to do and separate it into two different lists depending on whether the data is validated or not, for that the value of the registered validated.

```
List<MyVo> registeredBusinesses = new ArrayList<MyVo>();
List<MyVo> unregisteredBusinesses = new ArrayList<MyVo>();

for (MyVo map : dataList) {
    if (map.getValidated == 0) {
        unregisteredBusinesses.add(map);
    }else {
        registeredBusinesses.add(map);
    }
}
```

now the list of registered businesses I want to remove the data that is repeated with the same value from its registered field and make a new list. this is what it took but it doesn't work right

```
List<MyVo> duplicateList = registeredBusinesses.stream().filter(distictByRegistered(MyVo::getRegistered)).collect(Collectors.toList());


public static <T> Predicate<T> distictByRegistered(Function<?      super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
    Set<Object> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    return t -> seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t));
}
```

however using this method I get the following output:

{["validated":1,"name":"Fernando","registered":"008982"],
["validated":1,"name":"Jess","registered":"006782"]}

the output I want to obtain is the following:

the unregisteredBusinesses list:

```
{["validated":0,"name":"Orlando","registered":"008986"]}
```

the registeredBusinesses list:

```
{["validated":1,"name":"Jess","registered":"006782"]}
```

the registeredDuplicateBusinesses list:

```
{["validated":1,"name":"Fernando","registered":"008982"], 
["validated":1,"name":"Magda","registered":"008982"]}
```

I don't know how to do it, could you help me? I would like to use lambdas to reduce the code, for example of the first for when I separate into two lists

Comment: I fail to understand: you want to filter out all duplicate when `rregistered` is equals to 1 and based on `registered` value? Why are you not using `MyVo::getRegistered` instead of `Function.identity` as key? Then, use a merger (that throw away the duplicate (the default merger will throw an exception): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-

Comment: Hello, I already tried what you asked me but it still does not come out, edit the question, I do not know in what or you tell it to compare with the specific field to know if it is repeated or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for both registered and unregistered businesses. This is where instead of making use of 0 and 1, you could choose to implement the attribute as a boolean isRegistered such as 0 is false and 1 is true going forward. Your existing code with if-else could be re-written as :

```
Map<Boolean, List<MyVo>> partitionBasedOnRegistered = dataList.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(MyVo::isRegistered));
List<MyVo> unregisteredBusinesses = partitionBasedOnRegistered.get(Boolean.FALSE); // here
List<MyVo> registeredBusinesses = partitionBasedOnRegistered.get(Boolean.TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach looks almost correct, grouping by `Function.identity()` will properly flag duplicates (based on equals() implementation!), you could also group by an unique property/id in your object if you have one, what you're missing is to manipulate the resulting map to get a list with all duplicates. I've added comments describing what's happening here.

```
List<MyVo> duplicateList = registeredBusinesses.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity()))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1) //this is a stream of Map.Entry<MyVo, List<MyVo>>, then we want to check value.size() > 1
    .map(Map.Entry::getValue) //We convert this into a Stream<List<MyVo>>
    .flatMap(Collection::stream) //Now we want to have all duplicates in the same stream, so we flatMap it using Collections::stream
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); //On this stage we have a Stream<MyVo> with all duplicates, so we can collect it to a list.
```

Additionally, you could also use stream API to split `dataList` into registered and unRegistered.

First we create a method `isUnregistered` in MyVo

```
public boolean isUnregistered() {
  return getrRegistered() == 0;
}
```

Then

```
Map<Boolean, List<MyVo>> registeredMap = dataList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyVo::isUnregistered));
```

Where `map.get(true)` will be `unregisteredBusinesses` and `map.get(false)` `registeredBusinesses`

Comment: Hello, I already tried what you asked me but it still does not come out, edit the question, I do not know in what or you tell it to compare with the specific field to know if it is repeated or not

Comment: Function.identity() compares the entries by using itself, this is by checking the equals() method, you need to override equals() in your MyVo object and make it compare whatever means for you "unique".

Answer (score 0):

Familiarizing yourself with the concept of the [`Collectors.partitioningBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy(java.util.function.Predicate)) shall help you problem-solve this further. There are two places amongst your current requirement where it could be implied.

1. You are looking for both `registered` and `unregistered` businesses. This is where instead of making use of `0` and `1`, you could choose to implement the attribute as a `boolean isRegistered` such as 0 is `false` and 1 is `true` going forward. Your existing code with `if-else` could be re-written as :

   ```
   Map<Boolean, List<MyVo>> partitionBasedOnRegistered = dataList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(MyVo::isRegistered));
   List<MyVo> unregisteredBusinesses = partitionBasedOnRegistered.get(Boolean.FALSE); // here
   List<MyVo> registeredBusinesses = partitionBasedOnRegistered.get(Boolean.TRUE);
   ```
2. After you try to `groupBy` the `registered` businesses based on the registration number(despite of `identity`), you require both the duplicate elements and the ones which are unique as well. Effectively all entries, but again partitioned into two buckets, i.e. one with value size `== 1` and others with size `> 1`. Since grouping would ensure, minimum one element corresponding to each key, you can collect the required output with an additional mapping.

   ```
   Map<String, List<MyVo>> groupByRegistrationNumber = // group registered businesses by number

   Map<Boolean, List<List<MyVo>>> partitionBasedOnDuplicates = groupByRegistrationNumber
            .entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1,
                    Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
   ```

   If you access the `FALSE` values of the above map, that would provide you the `groupedRegisteredUniqueBusiness` and on the other hand values against `TRUE` key would provide you `groupedRegisteredDuplicateBusiness`.

Do take a note, that if you were to **flatten** this `List<List<MyVo>` in order to get `List<MyVo>` as output, you could also make use of the [flatMapping collector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39131049/1746118) which has a JDK inbuilt implementation with Java-9 and above.

Comment: Hello, I already tried what you asked me but it still does not come out, edit the question, I do not know in what or you tell it to compare with the specific field to know if it is repeated or not

Comment: @SebastianRuiz `groupByRegistrationNumber` would be specific to a field such as `...collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyVo::registrationNumber)`, and the count of values after grouping would convey if they are duplicates or not, that is where `e.getValue().size() > 1` is used.