# How to Convert a Map<String, List<List<String>>> to Map<String, List<String>>

Tags: java-8

```
 Map<String, List<String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
  Map<String, List<String>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
   map1.put("a", Lists.newArrayList("1","123"));
    map1.put("b", Lists.newArrayList("2","223"));

    map2.put("c", Lists.newArrayList("11","1123"));
    map2.put("a", Lists.newArrayList("22","2223"));
  Map<String, List<List<String>>> collect = Stream.of(map1, map2)
            .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                            Collectors.toList())
            ));
 System.out.println(collect);
```

print: {a=[[1, 123], [22, 2223, 1, 123]], b=[[2, 223]], c=[[11, 1123]]}

how can print:
{a=[22, 2223, 1, 123], b=[2, 223], c=[11, 1123]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a simple for loop and do it like this.

```
List<Map<String, List<String>>> source = Arrays.asList(map1, map2);
for (Map<String, List<String>> m : source) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> e : m.entrySet()) {
        target.computeIfAbsent(e.getKey(), unused -> new ArrayList<>())
            .addAll(e.getValue());
    }
}
```

A stream based counterpart would be something like this.

```
Map<String, List<String>> res = source.stream()
    .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
        Collectors.flatMapping(e -> e.getValue().stream(), Collectors.toList())));
```

The `Collectors.flatMapping` is available from java9 onwards. If you are using java8, I would recommend you to write your own custom collector for `flatMapping` and use it here. This will give you an easier migration strategy for Java9 too. You may find an explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130122/java-8-nested-multi-level-group-by/39131049#39131049).

Comment: Thank you for your answer， but the API( Collectors.flatMapping) is java9, and I use java8。Finally, I try another way：   map1.forEach((k, v) ->
                map2.merge(k, v, (v1, v2) -> {
                    v1.addAll(v2);
                    return v1;
                }));

Comment: Please see my edit and go through this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130122/java-8-nested-multi-level-group-by/39131049#39131049

Comment: Good solution, thank you @Ravindra Ranwala

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't create `List<List<String>>`s in the first place

```
Map<String, List<String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, List<String>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("a", Lists.newArrayList("1","123"));
map1.put("b", Lists.newArrayList("2","223"));

map2.put("c", Lists.newArrayList("11","1123"));
map2.put("a", Lists.newArrayList("22","2223"));

Map<String, List<String>> collect = Stream.of(map1, map2)
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                 Collectors.flatMapping(e -> e.getValue().stream(), Collectors.toList())));
```