# how can i return List<String>

Tags: list, dictionary, stream

how can i return only values of map with stream ?
Map<String,List> -> List

is the only way list.addAll ?

```
map.values().stream().filter(s->s.size()>1).collect(Collectors.toList()).stream());
```

Comment: this kind of question has been asked before I think [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71047692/how-to-convert-a-mapstring-listliststring-to-mapstring-liststring)

Comment: for more you can also check at [here](https://itnext.io/transforming-lists-into-maps-using-java-stream-api-b29ef743b440?source=post_internal_links---------2----------------------------&gi=a9f0b35ba6a1) and [here](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/04/10-examples-of-converting-list-to-map.html#axzz7jGj3hJV9). I think you should provide more code or add some example so I could know what are you trying to do