# Java Streams: Grouping a List by two fields

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of cars

`List<Car> cars = ...;`

A car has an `Owner` and and `Owner` has a `ContactNumber`

**Car**

```
public class Car {
    private Owner owner;
    public Owner getOwner(){
       return owner;
    }
}
```

**Owner**

```
public class Owner {
    private ContactNumber contactNumber;
    public ContactNumber getContactNumber() {
        return contactNumber;
    }
}
```

I know I can group cars by Owners using

```
Map<Owner, List<Car>> groupByOwner = cars.stream().collect(groupingBy(Car::getOwner));
```

Is there a way I can then use streams to group by `Owner` and `ContactNumber` knowing that one `ContactNumber` can only ever be associated with one `Owner`?

How would I also do this if a `ContactNumber` could be shared by multiple `Owner`s?

i.e to create the below map:

```
Map<Owner, List<Car>> groupByOwner = cars.stream().collect(groupingBy(Car::getOwner))
Map<ContactNumber, Map<Owner, List<Car>>> groupByContactNumberAndOwner = groupByOwner...
```

Comment: If `ContactNumber` is unique per owner then why have `Map` of owners per `ContactNumber` in `groupByContactNumberAndOwner`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group by multiple field names in java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342814/group-by-multiple-field-names-in-java-8)

Comment: @tsolakp You're right, If that restriction wasnt in place, i.e if a ContactNumber could be shared by multiple owners how would I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you know that

> one `ContactNumber` can only ever be associated with one `Owner`

Then, you don't need inner maps. Just group directly by `ContactNumber`:

```
Map<ContactNumber, List<Car>> groupByOwnerContactNumber = cars.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c.getOwner().getContactNumber()));
```

Don't be afraid to use lambda expressions ;)

---

**EDIT:**

As per the second part of your question:

> if a `ContactNumber` could be shared by multiple `Owners`

You could do a nested grouping by using the overloaded version of [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) that accepts a downstream collector:

```
Map<ContactNumber, Map<Owner, List<Car>>> groupByOwnerAndContactNumber = 
    cars.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            c -> c.getOwner().getContactNumber(),
            Collectors.groupingBy(Car::getOwner)));
```

Another way would be to group by a compound key `(ContactNumber, Owner)`. You can achieve this by letting the key be a `List<Object>`:

```
Map<List<Object>, List<Car>> groupByCompundOwnerContactNumber = 
    cars.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        c -> Arrays.asList(c.getOwner().getContactNumber(), c.getOwner())));
```

This doesn't require a nested grouping operation.

Note: if you're using Java 9 you can use `List.of` instead of `Arrays.asList`.

Comment: Thanks, if a contact number could be shared by multiple owners how would I do it differently?

Answer (score 5):

To get the `Map<ContactNumber, Map<Owner, List<Car>>>` collection I was looking for I had to do:

```
Map<ContactNumber, Map<Owner, List<Car>>> response = cars.stream()
                    .collect(groupingBy(c -> c.getOwner().getContactNumber(), groupingBy(Car::getOwner)));
```

Using the overloaded collector

```
groupingBy(Function<? super T, ? extends K> classifier, Collector<? super T, A, D> downstream)
```

Where you would use:

```
groupingBy(
    list element -> root key of the map, 
    groupingBy(list element -> second level key of the map)
);
```