# Group by two fields using Collectors

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a java object Record:

```
public Record(ZonedDateTime day, int ptid, String name, String category, int amount) {
        this.day= day;
        this.id= id;
        this.name = name;
        this.category = category;
        this.amount = amount;
}
```

I'm grouping a list of `Record`s by their `day`, and then creating a new `Record` which combines the `amount` field and returns a map:

```
Map<ZonedDateTime, Record> map = tempList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Record::getDay,
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.reducing((r1, r2) -> new Record(r1.getDay(),Integer.toString(r1.getId),r1.getName(),
                                r1.getCategory(),r1.getAmount() + r2.getAmount())),
                        Optional::get)));
```

I want to group the list by `day` AND `category`. So if `day` and `category` are the same, I would like to combine the `amount` field in a new `Record` like I am already doing. I need to add in another `Collectors.groupingBy` clause but the syntax just hasn't been working. I believe the return type would be `Map<ZonedDateTime, Map<String, List<Record>>>`. I also then need to convert the returned map into a `List`.

I've been trying to go off of this example [Group by multiple field names in java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342814/group-by-multiple-field-names-in-java-8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simplify the whole construct by using [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

```
Map<List<Object>, Record> map = tempList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            r -> List.of(r.getDay(), r.getCategory()), // or Arrays.asList
                            Record::new,
                            Record::merge));
```

The trick is to group by a composite key. In this case, we're using a `List<Object>` with both `Record.day` and `Record.category`. (`List` implements `Object.hashCode` and `Object.equals` as required, so it can be safely used as the key of any `Map`).

For the reduction to work, we need a copy constructor and a `merge` method:

```
public Record(Record r) {
    this(r.day, r.name, r.name, r.category, r.amount);
}

public Record merge(Record r) {
    this.amount += r.amount;
    return this;
}
```

Finally, to return the list of records, there's no need to do anything fancier than this:

```
List<Record> result = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```