# Java 8 Grouping Objects by HOUR

Tags: java

I have a List of Object made in this way:

```
public class Object{
    private Date date;
    private double value;

    //getters and setters
}
```

I need to take only Objects with hourly frequence.

My idea was to use a Java8 stream and groupingBy function in this way

```
Map<Integer, List<Object>> map = objects()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getDate().get(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY)));
```

but in this way i only take 24 elements (one per hour of day) even if I have multiple days in my list. How can i group by day/hour?

Comment: Can you group by day and then for each day group by hour?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group by multiple field names in java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342814/group-by-multiple-field-names-in-java-8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suggest you use a `LocalDateTime` here instead of `Date`.

Basically, you don't want to group by the hour *number*. You want to put each different hour in time in a different group, right? That means grouping by year, month, day, and hour.

One way to do this would be to group by the formatted date only up to the hour:

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHH").format(x));
```

Alternatively, truncate each date to hours using `truncatedTo`:

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try grouping it by both the day and the hour:

```
objects().collect(
      groupingBy(x -> x.getDate().get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_YEAR),
       groupingBy(x -> x.getDate().get(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY))));
```