# Convert nested map of streams.groupingBy() into list of POJOs

Tags: java, java-stream, lombok

I want to convert a nested map structure created by java streams + groupingBy into a list of POJOs, where each POJO represents one of the groups and also holds all the matching objects of that group.

I have the following code: I use [project lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) for convenience here (@Builder, @Data). Please let me know if that is confusing.

My goal is to prevent two points from happening:

1. Having deeply nested maps and
2. As a result: Looping over these nested maps via keySets or entrySets to actually do stuff if the entries

Instead, I'd love a clean and flat list of POJOs that represent the grouping and conveniently hold the matching entries for each group.

Find the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/gersta/convert-nested-stream-maps/tree/main) to run if locally, if you want.

**Edit 1:**
I've updated the code again to remove the lastname and add another "Gerrit" object to have two objects with the same grouping. I hope this makes the intent clearer.

**Edit 2:**
I have updated the code again to add a property on Person which is not part of the grouping.

I am looking for an output like this:

```
[
    Grouping(firstname=Jane, age=24, homeCountry=USA, persons=[Person(firstname=Jane, age=24, homeCountry=USA, favoriteColor=yellow)]),
    Grouping(firstname=gerrit, age=24, homeCountry=germany, persons=[
        Person(firstname=gerrit, age=24, homeCountry=germany, favoriteColor=blue), Person(firstname=gerrit, age=24, homeCountry=germany, favoriteColor=green)
    ])  
]
```

```
public class ConvertMapStreamToPojo {

    @Data
    @Builder
    static class Person {
        private String firstname;
        private int age;
        private String homeCountry;
        private String favoriteColor;
    }

    @Data
    static class Grouping {
        private String firstname;
        private int age;
        private String homeCountry;

        List<Person> persons;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person gerrit = Person.builder()
                .firstname("gerrit")
                .age(24)
                .homeCountry("germany")
                .favoriteColor("blue")
                .build();

        Person anotherGerrit = Person.builder()
                .firstname("gerrit")
                .age(24)
                .homeCountry("germany")
                .favoriteColor("green")
                .build();

        Person janeDoe = Person.builder()
                .firstname("Jane")
                .age(25)
                .homeCountry("USA")
                .favoriteColor("yellow")
                .build();

        List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(gerrit, anotherGerrit, janeDoe);

        Map<String, Map<Integer, Map<String, List<Person>>>> nestedGroupings = persons.stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getFirstname,
                                Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getAge,
                                        Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getHomeCountry)
                                )
                        )
                );

        /**
         * Convert the nested maps into a List<Groupings> where each group
         * holds a list of all matching persons
         */
        List<Grouping> groupings = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Grouping grouping: groupings) {
            String message = String.format("Grouping for firstname %s age %s and country %s", grouping.getFirstname(), grouping.getAge(), grouping.getHomeCountry());
            System.out.println(message);

            System.out.println("Number of persons inside this grouping: " + grouping.getPersons().size());
        }

        // example groupings

        /**
         *
         * [
         *  Grouping(firstname=Jane, age=24, homeCountry=USA, persons=[Person(firstname=Jane, age=24, homeCountry=USA, favoriteColor=yellow)]),
         *  Grouping(firstname=gerrit, age=24, homeCountry=germany, persons=[
         *      Person(firstname=gerrit, age=24, homeCountry=germany, favoriteColor=blue), Person(firstname=gerrit, age=24, homeCountry=germany, favoriteColor=green)
         *  ])  
         * ]
         *
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include all necessary code so it will compile.  Your classes are incomplete.

Comment: By looking at the nested map solution it seems that a data base would be more appropriate.

Comment: Can you clarify the intend of your grouping? Is there any scenario where your Grouping has more than 1 Person in it?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to keep the example short and thus there are never more than one person In the same group. But it could surely happen to have two objects in the same group, thus the list has > 1 entries

Comment: @WJS I've updated my description with a link to the GitHub repo and also updated the code itself. Hope it helps

Comment: @Sorin: I've updated my code example to hopefully make the intent clearer by adding another "Gerrit" object with identical properties

Comment: @WJS A database is not suitable for us here as first we only have a few entries in the original persons list (100 - 200) and we need to to run as quickly as possible, thus I'd assume that pure Java is faster, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure about the purpose of `Grouping` object because upon converting the maps to `List<Grouping>` the list of persons will actually contain duplicate persons.

This can be achieved with plain `groupingBy` person and converting the `Map.Entry` to `Grouping`.

**Update**
If the "key" part of `Grouping` has fewer fields than `Person` (`favoriteColor` has been added recently to `Person`), it's worth to implement another POJO representing the key of `Grouping`:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
static class GroupingKey {
    private String firstname;
    private int age;
    private String homeCountry;

    public GroupingKey(Person person) {
        this(person.firstname, person.age, person.homeCountry);
    }
}
```

Then the instance of `GroupingKey` may be used in `Grouping` to avoid duplication.

Assuming that all-args constructor and a mapping constructor are implemented in `Grouping`

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
static class Grouping {
    // Not needed in toString, related fields are available in Person instances
    @ToString.Exclude
    private GroupingKey key;

    List<Person> persons;
    
    public Grouping(Map.Entry<GroupingKey, List<Person>> e) {
        this(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
    }
}
```

Then implementation could be as follows:

```java
List<Grouping> groupings = persons.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(GroupingKey::new))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(Grouping::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

groupings.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output (test data changed slightly, key part is excluded):

```
Grouping(persons=[Person(firstname=Jane, age=24, homeCountry=USA, favoriteColor=Azure)])
Grouping(persons=[Person(firstname=gerrit, age=24, homeCountry=USA, favoriteColor=Red)])
Grouping(persons=[Person(firstname=gerrit, age=24, homeCountry=germany, favoriteColor=Black), Person(firstname=gerrit, age=24, homeCountry=germany, favoriteColor=Green)])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! :-) It's going into the direction I'm hoping for. Did you add the Gerrit + USA entry?

If I have a nested grouping by using groupingBy more than once, how could I convert only the deepest grouping (Map<K,V>) to a grouping POJO with your solution?

Comment: Yes, I added that `Gerrit + USA`.  There's no need to create intermediate maps using multiple `groupingBy` if you need to use the deepest grouping by all the properties of `Person` -- it's the same as if you grouped once by `Person`.

Comment: I just tried your solution. I think I've updated my code after your suggestion here, sorry.
There are now properties on the objects which are not relevant for the grouping, thus the objects are not identical.

Comment: What exactly happens when using the identity function (x -> x) in a groupingBy? Does it check whether X as a key is already present via the equals method of x's class? Or in a different way?

If it is the equals method, than this might be difficult to do in my case as the favoriteColor is different on both objects (they are thus not equal), but should still be present in the same group

Comment: 1. There were no `favoriteColor` in original question/code of `Person` class. 2. Yes, `x -> x` uses `equals()`. 3. It may be worth to implement a separate POJO representing the key value and then copy the key to `Grouping`, please check the update.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a duplicate person in your solution, then `grouping` variable will hold only non-duplicate values. I believe it is not the right intention you want.

To achieve that you hold also duplicates, you can create a "grouping key" inside `Person` class to group values appropriately (or even [use records](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28344135/2019964), depending on your Java version).

```
    @Data
    @Builder
    static class Person {
        private String firstname;
        private String lastname;
        private int age;
        private String homeCountry;

        String groupingKey() {
            return firstname + "/" + lastname + "/" + age + "/" + homeCountry;
        }
    }

    @Data
    @Builder
    static class Grouping {

        private String firstname;
        private String lastname;
        private int age;
        private String homeCountry;

        List<Person> persons;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person johnDoe = Person.builder()
                .firstname("John")
                .lastname("Doe")
                .age(25)
                .homeCountry("USA")
                .build();

        Person janeDoe = Person.builder()
                .firstname("Jane")
                .lastname("Doe")
                .age(25)
                .homeCountry("USA")
                .build();

        Person duplicateJaneDoe = Person.builder()
                .firstname("Jane")
                .lastname("Doe")
                .age(25)
                .homeCountry("USA")
                .build();

        List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(johnDoe, janeDoe, duplicateJaneDoe);

        Map<String, List<Person>> groupedPersons = persons.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::groupingKey));

        // Since now you have grouped persons, you can go through map entries 
        // and fill your Grouping object list by splitting the key or just taking
        // the first object from the person list.

        List<Grouping> groupings = new ArrayList<>();

        groupedPersons.forEach((key, value) -> {
            String[] personBits = key.split("/");
            Grouping grouping = new Grouping.GroupingBuilder()
                    .firstname(personBits[0])
                    .lastname(personBits[1])
                    .age(Integer.parseInt(personBits[2]))
                    .homeCountry(personBits[3])
                    .persons(value)
                    .build();
            groupings.add(grouping);
        });
    }
```

Comment: This looks interesting, thanks for sharing! However, what do you mean by grouping wont hold duplicates? Maybe my wording was wrong: I meant that both "Gerrit" objects will have the same grouping due to identical properties and thus end of in the same nested map. Right?

Comment: Sure, you're welcome. I mean that your solution has an issue with duplicates. You currently have two "gerrit" objects. Your solution with nested groupings collects to map two entries which is correct, however in the collected map entry person list there is only one "gerrit" which is incorrect, I assume. There should be both "gerrit" objects, no?

Comment: I want both my Gerrit objects in the same grouping, although they are not 100% identical (the properties relevant for the grouping are however identical)