# Finding the duplicate values and the number of occurrences of the same in Java Map

Tags: java, java-8

I am using Java.
I have a Map as shown below :

```
List<Map<String, String>> listMap = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
```

I am inserting Map objects with some key value pairs into the above `List<Map<String, String>> listMap`.

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();

map1.put("jobDescription", "Java Developer-SpringBoot");
map1.put("interviewType", "L2");
map1.put("hired", "yes");
listMap.add(map1);

Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();

map2.put("jobDescription", "Java Developer-SpringBoot");
map2.put("interviewType", "L2");
map2.put("hired", "yes");
listMap.add(map2);

Map<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
map3.put("jobDescription", "Java Developer-SpringBoot");
map3.put("interviewType", "L1");
map3.put("hired", "no");
listMap.add(map3);
```

Now, I want to iterate

```
listMap(`List<Map<String, String>> listMap`)
```

and then find if there are any duplicate/same values for the key `jobDescription`  in any of the map, then check for the value of `interviewType` key's value and see the number of occurrences of the value.

In the above example, the values for the key `jobDescription` is same in all the Map objects(i.e.`Java Developer-SpringBoot`). Then verify the values for the key `interviewType` and see the number of occurrences of each value(In the above case `L2` repeated twice and `L1` once). Finally I need to construct one more `Map` that contains my observations.

For example(This data is depicted for illustration purpose, but this should actually go into a new `Map`:

```
"jobDescription"             - "Count of L2" -  "Count of L1"
-------------------------------------------------------------------
"Java Developer-SpringBoot"      2                 1
```

Can anyone help me on this?

The code that I am trying is given below:

```
package com.test;
    
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List<Map<String, String>> listMap = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();

        map1.put("jobDescription", "Java Developer-SpringBoot");
        map1.put("interviewType", "L2");
        map1.put("hired", "yes");
        listMap.add(map1);
        
        Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        
        map2.put("jobDescription", "Java Developer-SpringBoot");
        map2.put("interviewType", "L2");
        map2.put("hired", "yes");
        listMap.add(map2);
       
        Map<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map3.put("jobDescription", "Java Developer-SpringBoot");
        map3.put("interviewType", "L1");
        map3.put("hired", "no");
        listMap.add(map3);
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> requiredMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
        for (Map<String, String> someMap : listMap) {
            int count = Collections.frequency(someMap.values(), "L2");
            
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group by multiple field names in java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342814/group-by-multiple-field-names-in-java-8)

Comment: Is there any reason you can't create a class Job with field jobDescription, interviewType and hired? It looks strange to use map to store your data.

Comment: @samabcde, Thanks for the response. Creating a separate class is better idea too. Could you please share any solution with separate class being created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks strange to use map to store the data, as:

1. All values are limited to the same type(String).
2. There is no limitation on the keys.

Modelling a class `Job` is a more proper way. Then follow @Joe comment suggestion, [Group by multiple field names in java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342814/group-by-multiple-field-names-in-java-8)

Below program will output

> Java Developer-SpringBoot L1:1, L2:2

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<>();
        jobs.add(new Job("Java Developer-SpringBoot", "L2", "yes"));
        jobs.add(new Job("Java Developer-SpringBoot", "L2", "yes"));
        jobs.add(new Job("Java Developer-SpringBoot", "L1", "no"));
        Map<String, Map<String, Long>> jobDescriptionToInterviewTypeToCountMapMap = jobs.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Job::getJobDescription,
                Collectors.groupingBy(Job::getInterviewType, Collectors.counting())));
        for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Long>> entry : jobDescriptionToInterviewTypeToCountMapMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue().entrySet().stream().map((e) ->
                    e.getKey() + ":" + e.getValue()).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
        }
    }

    public static class Job {
        public Job(String jobDescription, String interviewType, String hired) {
            this.jobDescription = jobDescription;
            this.interviewType = interviewType;
            this.hired = hired;
        }

        private String jobDescription;
        private String interviewType;
        private String hired;

        public String getJobDescription() {
            return jobDescription;
        }

        public void setJobDescription(String jobDescription) {
            this.jobDescription = jobDescription;
        }

        public String getInterviewType() {
            return interviewType;
        }

        public void setInterviewType(String interviewType) {
            this.interviewType = interviewType;
        }

        public String getHired() {
            return hired;
        }

        public void setHired(String hired) {
            this.hired = hired;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Stream over your list and filter maps having an entry with key: `jobDescription` and value: `Java Developer-SpringBoot` , flatmap to get all entries of all maps, filter entries having `interviewType` as key, map each entry to its value, collect to map using `Function.identity()` and mapping to frequency:

```
Map<String,Long> result =
listMap.stream()
        .filter(m -> m.entrySet().contains(Map.entry("jobDescription","Java Developer-SpringBoot")))
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        .filter(e -> e.getKey().equals("interviewType"))
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()));

System.out.println(result);

//output: {L1=1, L2=2}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But here `Java Developer-SpringBoot` is dynamic value. i.e. we  can get `jobDescription` value as anything. Could you please advice?